# In Pathfinder Society play, how many times can you purchase a "found item"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

If my character receives a chronicle sheet that lists, say, a Potion of Cure Moderate Wounds (300gp) does this mean I may purchase the potion one time and must then cross it off my chronicle sheet?  Or may I purchase one before each new adventure?

(A rules or forum reference would be most welcome!)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! glad you are here!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Items listed on your Chronicle sheet are considered "always available".  In other words, they join low-level potions, scrolls, weapons and armor as things your character can buy at any time.

From the [Guide to PFS Organized Play](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/v5748btpy84k4) (p. 18):

> Every item listed on your Chronicle 
>   sheets is considered always available for purchase for you, 
>   regardless of whether it’s on your first Chronicle sheet or 
>   your 21st Chronicle sheet. The only exceptions are items 
>   that have a purchase limit. You may never purchase more 
>   of that item throughout the life of your character than 
>   the number amount listed as the purchase limit.

As it says, exceptions to the "always available" default will be noted explicitly, either as a "purchase limit" or with a note like, "cross this item off of your Chronicle sheet after it has been used."